# try to send from data to v-for in Vue but it look like missing something

Tags: vue.js

I use v-for in html is correct way or not or I can not use v-for
in vue3  'items:' is defined but never used  but i try to use in iteration with v-for how to fix it I am not sure the way that

```html
<template>     
      <div id="app">     
  <table>
       <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
          <td><input v-model.number="item.qty" size="10"></td>
          <td><input v-model.number="item.price" size="10"></td>
          <td><input v-model.number="subtotalRow[index]" readonly size="10"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
         <td>{{total}}</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
     
  </template>
 
  <script>
 
  export default {
 
    data() {
      items: [
        {qty: 5, price: 25 },       
        {qty: 3, price: 88 }
        ]
      return {};
    },
    computed: {      
      subtotalRow() {
             .....
        },
        total() {
             ...
        } 
    }   
  };
  </script>
```

Comment: what makes you think the `v-for` is the issue?  are you receiving any errors in your dev console?  your `v-for` will technically work the way it is now so the error must be elsewhere in your code. I'm going to guess the issue is with `subtotalRow`... there's no real way I can make sense of v-model being a computed property with an array index.  Since the input is `readonly` it seems inappropriate to be using v-model which is meant for two-way binding.  just set `:value` instead, e.g. `<input readonly :value="item.qty * item.price">`

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed another notable error:  the `items` array inside `data()` is supposed to be _inside_ the `return` statement.  data is a function and all data properties must be returned from it.  See the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) for more information.  My other comment still holds true but fixing this will resolve the specific error you're asking about.

Comment: 13:9  error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key
  33:7  error  'items:' is defined but never used                            no-unused-labels

Comment: subtotalRow() {
          return this.items.map((item) => {
            return Number(item.qty * item.price)
          });
        },
        total() {
          return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
            return total + item.qty * item.price;
          }, 0);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I can fix by change

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in items"> {{index}}. {{item.name}} </div>
```

to

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id"> {{index}}. {{item.name}} </div>
```

and change data return  to

data() {

```
  return {items: [
    {qty: 5, price: 25 },
    {qty: 2, price: 16 },
    {qty: 8, price: 320 },
    {qty: 3, price: 88 }
    ]};
},
```